# Attribute values must be constant while injecting views with RoboGuice

Tags: android, android-resources, roboguice, android-identifiers

I have a project contains 2 applications and **1 library module.**
I would like to use RoboGuice because of the view injection feature.

Currently i cannot inject views in my library module, **because generated ids in the R.java file are not constants** and i get "Attribute values must be constants" error. [See explanation here. Since ADT 14, in a library project, ids are not constants because of an optimization feature.](http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields)

I could decide to use RoboGuice within the 2 application and simply not use in my library module, but I also wondering is there a way to somehow make a workaround to this?

Maybe somehow **force** A. Studio to generate constant values **even in library modules?**

Comment: I don't know solution to your exact problem, but for view injection you can check out [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Comment: I also have this problem with Butterknife.